# How to combine two observations in a data frame and fill NAs with contradicting entries

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to combine like observations such that `NA`s in observation A are filled with entries in observation B.  If observation A and observation B have contradicting entries, e.g., two different values in the same field, I'd like the resulting data frame to return an `NA` in that field.

**Example.**

Consider the following data frame

```
df1 <- data.frame(APPLIANT = c("tom", "tom"), 
                  PERMIT = c(31, 31), 
                  ISSUED_YR = c("2018", NA), 
                  TRANSFERED = c("Y", "N"))
```

It looks like

```
  APPLIANT PERMIT ISSUED_YR TRANSFERED
1      tom     31      2018          Y
2      tom     31      <NA>          N
```

I'd like my final data frame to look like

```
  APPLIANT PERMIT ISSUED_YR TRANSFERED
1      tom     31      2018         NA
```

I was thinking of using an apply function.  maybe something like

```
apply(df1, 2, FUN = function(one_col){
if(length(unique(one_col)) == 1){one_col}else{ one_col[!is.na(one_col)]}
})
```

But im not sure how to handle the 'contradicting' data points in an elegant way.... I also do not feel like my solution is that elegant to begin with.  If there is something simpler that would be ideal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help if there is only two observations involved:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(
    length(unique(.x)) > 1 & !any(is.na(.x)) ~ NA_character_,
    TRUE ~ as.character(coalesce(.x, .x[!is.na(.x)]))
  ))) %>%
  distinct()

  APPLIANT PERMIT ISSUED_YR TRANSFERED
1      tom     31      2018       <NA>
```

Comment: Perfect!!!  Yes, there are only two observations involved.  I figured it'd be too complex to try to do a group_by on the whole data set.  Instead, I'd just loop through the like-observations and apply the following.

Comment: In fact we don't need `group_by` here, since there are only two observations and we take non-`NA` values from one to fill in the other. If there were more than two then we should change it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than 1 unique value in a column return `NA` else return the non-NA value.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(APPLIANT) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~if(n_distinct(., na.rm = TRUE) > 1) NA else na.omit(.)[1]))

#APPLIANT PERMIT ISSUED_YR TRANSFERED
#  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <lgl>     
#1 tom          31 2018      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the above suggestions worked on my example data but not on the actual data.  In my real data set, I have some columns that are date objects, maybe this posed a problem

What seemed to work for me but is not as 'pretty' was the following

```
df %>%
      mutate_all(funs(if(length(unique(.)) == 1){ 
        unique(.)
      }else{
        if(any(is.na(.))){
          (.)[!is.na(.)]
        }else{
          NA
          }
        })) %>% 
      distinct()
```